# Disable Spring Boot HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration but still getting a related error

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {
    HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class, JndiConnectionFactoryAutoConfiguration.class, XADataSourceAutoConfiguration.class,
    JndiDataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, ...)
```

like code above, I disable pretty much Auto Configuration Classes provided by Spring Boot, because I want to make my rpc framework more cleaner, but I keep getting this error which is so weird, I take a look at HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration constructor, It requires a Datasource bean, but I've already diable HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration, why it still creating this bean?

> Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'javax.sql.DataSource' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}

Answer (score 0):

When you disable `HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration` you have to manually provide `DataSource` bean in your configuration, otherwise Spring is unable to find it within the Application Context and throws exception that you've faced

Comment: take a look at HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration constructor, It requires a Datasource bean, but I've already diable HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration, why it still creating this bean?

Answer (score 0):

problem resolved! it turns out that I have two test Main classes in my classpath, and when I delete one, problem disappear, so weird. the two Main classes shows below:

```
@XproPluginApplication
public class ServerMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(ServerMain.class);
    }
}

@XproPluginApplication
public class ClientMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(ClientMain.class);

        Invoker invoker = context.getBean(Invoker.class);
        while (true) {
            try {
                invoker.invokeVoidAsyncCallback();

                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
            }
        }
    }
}

@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = { HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class...}
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@Import(XproPluginRegistrar.class)
public @interface XproPluginApplication {
    RunMode runMode() default RunMode.SERVER;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you don't need the datasource.
Remove it from the auto-config process:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
```